# What is the equivalent (programmatically) of cat /dev/something > file.txt

Tags: cat, io

I'm copying a video from a camera stream using a command `cat /dev/video0 > file.mpeg`
This works perfectly, however I want too break up the file into smaller chunks... So I've been waiting pressing Ctrl+C.. Wanted to automate that so created a batch script that will wait X minutes then halt the job, meanwhile show a progress bar. Works great however I want to take it another step.. I have an XML file that contains the exact times and file names, I have a mono program that parses this file.

Here's the question.. How can I programmatically run this cat command. Sure I could execute a system command. But I was thinking of just doing the entire application in the same language.  I can open a file to write as a binary write and read say 1000 bytes at a time... But what is cat doing? Does it know how much/ how fast to read somehow?

Comment: I think and I might be wrong, that the `cat` reads and outputs the file as fast as the source device, system and CPU allows.

Comment: You could use `dd` to limit how much data is written from the device to stdout or a file.

Answer (score 2):

### Let `timeout` kill `cat`

Since it works well enough with `cat` and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, the following command line should work with data according to the question and assuming 5 seconds play-time to be recorded.

```
timeout 5 cat /dev/video0 > file.mpeg
```

`cat` is a simple tool for reading/writing data. There is no way to set the speed or time interval for the data transfer in `cat`. You have to control it outside `cat`. But there are many other tools.

### Use the built-in features in `ffmpeg`

It is also possible to use the multimedia tool `ffmpeg`. There is a steep learning curve, but when you get into using it, you will find that it is a very powerful tool. There are detailed instructions in the manual **`man ffmpeg`** but it is better to search for a suitable tutorial via the internet.

I have tested the following command line with conversion from an MTS file to an mpeg file. I have not tested it from a device, but I think it will work. You may want to control the conversion (to be different from the defaults) using more options in the command line.

```
ffmpeg -t 5 -i /dev/video0 file.mpeg
```

where `-t 5` means that 5 seconds are recorded.

The following command line may be an important improvement,

> ```
> ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f segment -segment_time 10:0 out%03d.mp4
> ```
>
> It will split the input into files of 10 minutes length. you should look at the docs [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#toc-segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment)

**`ffmpeg`versions**

- In my working computer with Lubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, there is `ffmpeg version 3.4.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1`, so version 3.4.4. This is what you get if you install from Ubuntu's repositories. Other linux distros and versions have probably other versions (newer or older).
- The link (to https://ffmpeg.org) describes version 4.1, and some features in this version may not be there in the older version. This version is more advanced, but may be more complicated to get and to keep up to date with bugfixes.

Comment: @user1529413, The community is downvoting this answer. If you find it useful, please let me know. Otherwise I will delete it (after some time for you to test it).

Comment: Take a look at the `timeout` command, as in `timeout $ptime cat ...`, which seems to do pretty much everything your script does. (Not entirely sure why you're being downvoted, other than the OP asked for code in `mono` to replace `cat...`, which is a low-research question in itself.)

Comment: @roaima, Thanks for teaching about `timeout` :-) I replaced the separate 'sleep' and 'kill' commands with 'timeout', and the shellscript with a oneliner. Now let us wait for the response from the OP.

Comment: What about improving instead of deleting it? using `ffmpeg` is the way to go: `ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f segment -segment_time 10:0 out%03d.mp4` will split the input into files of 10 minutes length. you should look at the docs [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#toc-segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment).

Comment: @roaima `timeout` is not portable; and it also has its share of bugs and annoyances.

Comment: This is very helpful information, it annoys me to no end that's it's been down voted before I can even see it. Stack overflow has a major problem it needs to address, you've created a system that chases away people. This comment no doubt will be down voted as well.

Comment: @user1529413, I will try to keep the answer alive :-) There are helpful comments by roaima and pizdelect, so things are improving.

Comment: @user1529413, I would recommend that you test all methods: 1. `timeout ... cat` and 2. `ffmpeg` and tell us which way you want to go (and if you need more help along that way); 3. Or if you try the corresponding things in `mono` (I know nothing about that tool). -- My guess is that `ffmpeg` will give you the best control of what you are doing (but it may demand too much from the computer hardware), so you had better test it out.

Comment: @pizdelect the OP is using `/dev/video0` and `mono` so I guessed the target platform was Linux-based. (I accept that it's not actually stated, though.) Given that assumption `timeout` seemed to be a reasonable expectation. These assumptions notwithstanding you are correct in that it's not portable. I'm not aware of issues with it, but maybe that's because I don't use it heavily.